# javascript - Sum values from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sum

I'm trying to sum the specific value from json array:

```
    ([{"DESPRO":"PLANILLA DE EMPLEADOS","ANIO":"2013","MES":"06","NROPER":"201306","PLAGRPCON":"3","GRUPO_CONCEPTO":"APORTES","CODCON":"3010 ","CONCEPTO":"ESSALUD ","VALOR":"106,1"},

{"DESPRO":"PLANILLA DE EMPLEADOS","ANIO":"2013","MES":"06","NROPER":"201306","PLAGRPCON":"2","GRUPO_CONCEPTO":"DESCUENTOS","CODCON":"2030 ","CONCEPTO":"ADELANTO DE QUINCENA ","VALOR":"350"},

{"DESPRO":"PLANILLA DE EMPLEADOS","ANIO":"2013","MES":"06","NROPER":"201306","PLAGRPCON":"2","GRUPO_CONCEPTO":"DESCUENTOS","CODCON":"2604 ","CONCEPTO":"ADE. MOVILIDAD 1ER","VALOR":"48"},

{"DESPRO":"PLANILLA DE EMPLEADOS","ANIO":"2013","MES":"06","NROPER":"201306","PLAGRPCON":"2","GRUPO_CONCEPTO":"DESCUENTOS","CODCON":"2605 ","CONCEPTO":"ADE. MOVILIDAD 2DO","VALOR":"56"},


EMPLEADOS","ANIO":"2013","MES":"06","NROPER":"201306","PLAGRPCON":"2","GRUPO_CONCEPTO":"DESCUENTOS","CODCON":"2090 ","CONCEPTO":"AFP-PRIMA DE SEGURO","VALOR":"16,27"}, .... etc etc
```

In this case sum the VALORs from the array and put in any variable on javascript.

I got this code:

```
// some JS code
for (var i in datos){
   var HABERES = parseInt(datos[i].VALOR, 10);
   HABERES += HABERES;

   alert(HABERES);
}
```

When the alert goes, the result is not the correct..

Is there any problem(s) with that code?

Thank for answers..

Comment: `HABERES += HABERES;`.  Why are you adding the value to itself?

Comment: to increment it ? Is this wrong? ... I tried creating another value (`var SUM += HABERES`) but the result still isn't correct.

Comment: The question seems to be about how to process an array of objects in JavaScript than to be about JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something [like](http://jsfiddle.net/QPLfW/);

```
var HABERES = 0;
for (var i in datos){
   HABERES += parseInt(datos[i].VALOR, 10);
   alert(HABERES);
}
```

Comment: I put your `alert(HABERES)` after the for and works fine :) ... In your case, the result is 6 !! .. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you actually want, but I think it's this.  Start with `HABERES` at 0 and add the values in the loop.

```
var HABERES = 0;
for (var i in datos){
   HABERES += parseInt(datos[i].VALOR, 10);

   console.log(HABERES);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGYTH/1/

Answer (score 0):

Replace `,` with `.`

then `parseFloat`

```
var HABERES = 0;
for (var i in datos){
 HABERES += parseFloat(datos[i].VALOR.replace(',','.'));
}
alert(HABERES);
```

`HABERES.replace('.',',');` if you want comma on the result.

javascript uses the . as decimal separator.

parseFloat returns also decimal values.

http://jsfiddle.net/qGYTH/3/ Explosion Pills fiddle with my code.