# loop through the objects inside the array and sum it up

Tags: javascript

I have a an array consist of datas , where each datas has multiple subDatas,

```
var res = [
    {
        data1:{subData1:56, subData2:0, subData3:45},
        data2:{subData2:565, subData3:67, subData4:45},
        data3:{subData1:45, subData3:0},
        data4:{subData1:32, subData2:0, subData3:47},
        data5:{subData1:107, subData2:34, subData3:65},
        data6:{subData3:123, subData4:43},
        data7:{subData1:432, subData2:67, subData3:78},
        data8:{subData4:23, subData5:432, subData6:654},

    }
  ];
```

i need to get the sum of each subDatas in an array, i have figured out the solution but how can i reduce the code . Please find the below code for solving and suggest a better optimized way. I am using underscore js too.

```js
var res = [
    {
        data1:{subData1:56, subData2:0, subData3:45},
        data2:{subData2:565, subData3:67, subData4:45},
        data3:{subData1:45, subData3:0},
        data4:{subData1:32, subData2:0, subData3:47},
        data5:{subData1:107, subData2:34, subData3:65},
        data6:{subData3:123, subData4:43},
        data7:{subData1:432, subData2:67, subData3:78},
        data8:{subData4:23, subData5:432, subData6:654},

    }
  ];
  var values = Object.values(res[0])
  var arrayOfItems = [];
  var sums = {};

  values.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)).map(item => {item.map(subItem => arrayOfItems.push(subItem))})
 
  arrayOfItems = _.uniq(arrayOfItems)

  _.each(values, function (item) {
      _.each(arrayOfItems, function (color) {
          if(sums.hasOwnProperty(color)){
              sums[color] = sums[color]  + ( item[color] ? item[color] : 0 )
          }else{
              sums[color] = 0 + (item[color] ? item[color] : 0)
          }
      });
  });
  
  
  
  var arrOfSubDatasTotal = Object.keys(sums).map(item => ({name:item, total:sums[item]}))
  
  var totalOfSubDatas = Object.values(sums).reduce((a,b) => a + b)
  
  
  console.log("array Of SubDatas Total =>", arrOfSubDatasTotal)
  
    console.log("total Of SubDatas =>", totalOfSubDatas)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221455/how-to-sum-json-array)

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390281/javascript-sum-values-from-json

Answer (score 0):

Try following using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)

**LOGIC**

Create an object with keys as `subData{number}` and value as the **sum of its values**.

To create object, use `Array.reduce` to iterate over each object in array and then `Object.values` to get all the values in the object. Iterate over each value using `Array.forEach` and then for each object, use `Object.entries` to add / update the entry in intermediate object (**reduce accumulator**).

While creating the object, sum all the values to create the `total` of all the `subData's`. Finally transform `object` to `array` using `Object.entries` and use `Array.map` to convert it into the desired format.

```js
var res = [{data1:{subData1:56, subData2:0, subData3:45},data2:{subData2:565, subData3:67, subData4:45},data3:{subData1:45, subData3:0},data4:{subData1:32, subData2:0, subData3:47},data5:{subData1:107, subData2:34, subData3:65},data6:{subData3:123, subData4:43},data7:{subData1:432, subData2:67, subData3:78},data8:{subData4:23, subData5:432, subData6:654}}];

let total = 0;
let result = Object.entries(
      res.reduce((a,c) => {
          Object.values(c).forEach(
              o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => {
                  a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + v;
                  total += v;
              })
          );
          return a;
      }, {})
  ).map(([k,v]) => ({name: k, total : v}));
  
console.log(result);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Sum` monoid to whip through that list

```
import propOr from 'crocks/helpers/propOr'
import curry from 'crocks/helpers/curry'
import mreduceMap from 'crocks/helpers/mreduceMap'
import Sum from 'crocks/Sum'

var res = [{
  data1:{subData1:56, subData2:0, subData3:45},
  data2:{subData2:565, subData3:67, subData4:45},
  data3:{subData1:45, subData3:0},
  data4:{subData1:32, subData2:0, subData3:47},
  data5:{subData1:107, subData2:34, subData3:65},
  data6:{subData3:123, subData4:43},
  data7:{subData1:432, subData2:67, subData3:78},
  data8:{subData4:23, subData5:432, subData6:654},
}];

const data = Object.values(res[0])

const getSubData = i => propOr(0, 'subData' + i)

const getDataSum = curry(i => mreduceMap(Sum, getSubData(i)))


console.log(getDataSum(1, data))
// 672 - the sum of all subData1 properties in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in pure JS. Hope it helps.

```js
const res = [{
    data1:{subData1:56, subData2:0, subData3:45},
    data2:{subData2:565, subData3:67, subData4:45},
    data3:{subData1:45, subData3:0},
    data4:{subData1:32, subData2:0, subData3:47},
    data5:{subData1:107, subData2:34, subData3:65},
    data6:{subData3:123, subData4:43},
    data7:{subData1:432, subData2:67, subData3:78},
    data8:{subData4:23, subData5:432, subData6:654},
}];

const sums = {};

// For each item on your array

res.forEach((item) => {

    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {

       Object.keys(item[key]).forEach((sub) => {
           
           // Initialize its position on the sum object
           
           if (!sums[sub]) sums[sub] = { sum: 0, name: sub };

            sums[sub].sum += item[key][sub];
       });
   });
});

// Get the total of the subData
const total = Object.values(sums).reduce((acc, val) => acc += val.sum, 0.0);

console.log('Sums', Object.values(sums));
console.log('Total', total);
```